Wireless access point creation using netplan and nmcli is broken on Ubuntu 24.04-1
Here is the netplan entry for the access point.
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-1604818c-a141-4e8f-b6ab-a7075808fc9d:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "wlo1"
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      access-points:
        "test":
          band: "2.4GHz"
          channel: 10
          mode: "ap"
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "1604818c-a141-4e8f-b6ab-a7075808fc9d"
            name: "wlo1"
            passthrough:
              connection.autoconnect: "false"
              ipv4.address1: "10.161.0.1/24"
              ipv6.method: "disabled"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "1604818c-a141-4e8f-b6ab-a7075808fc9d"
        name: "wlo1"

This is what Network Manager logs when I try to bring up the access point.
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0911] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'wlo1' (1604818c-a141-4e8f-b6ab-a7075808fc9d)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0911] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): activation-stage: schedule activate_stage1_device_prepare
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0911] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="1604818c-a141-4e8f-b6ab-a7075808fc9d" name="wlo1" pid=7218 uid=0 result="success"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0912] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): activation-stage: invoke activate_stage1_device_prepare
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0912] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip4: set state pending (was none, reason: stage1)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0912] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip6: set state pending (was none, reason: stage1)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0912] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0912] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (2): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0913] active-connection[c231a285100c5034]: set state activating (was unknown)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0914] active-connection[c231a285100c5034]: check-master-ready: not signalling (state activating, no master)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0914] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: scan-periodic-allowed=0, scan-explicit-allowed=0
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0914] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: kickoff: don't scan (periodic scan currently not allowed)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0914] policy: block-autoconnect: unblocking port profiles for controller ifname="wlo1", uuid="1604818c-a141-4e8f-b6ab-a7075808fc9d"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0914] manager: default-route-metric: ifindex 4 reserves metric 600 (aspired 600)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0914] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (1): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0914] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: removed 28:80:88:EE:3C:6F "peglegpete"                        [ a   1  62% P_ __ W:0000 R:0188 ] 109.505s sup:/9 [nm:/11]
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0915] dbus-object[b36df5791ab8fc7f]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/11"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0915] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: removed 28:80:88:F4:8B:37 "peglegpete"                        [ a  36  32% P_ __ W:0000 R:0188 ] 109.505s sup:/10 [nm:/12]
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0916] dbus-object[bb8b920a02d35de5]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/12"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0916] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: removed 28:80:88:F4:8A:BD "peglegpete"                        [ a   6  47% P_ __ W:0000 R:0188 ] 109.504s sup:/19 [nm:/21]
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0916] dbus-object[34c5039f50ba5240]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/21"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0917] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: removed 30:B1:B5:75:5E:EE "BT-7RAWJR"                         [ a   1  35% P_ W_ W:0000 R:0188 ] 109.504s sup:/20 [nm:/22]
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0917] dbus-object[3eddc31c152a862b]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/22"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0917] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: removed 28:80:88:EE:3C:71 "peglegpete"                        [ a  36  22% P_ __ W:0000 R:0188 ] 109.504s sup:/21 [nm:/23]
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0918] dbus-object[748943f1422eb896]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/23"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0918] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: removed 72:B1:B5:75:5E:EF "EE WiFi"                           [ a   1  37% __ __ W:0000 R:0000 ] 109.504s sup:/22 [nm:/24]
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0918] dbus-object[97db29cf83bf7242]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/24"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0919] dbus-object[b36df5791ab8fc7f]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/25"
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0920] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: added   64:6E:E0:6A:EC:30 "test"                              [ #  10   0% __ __ W:0000 R:0000 ]          sup:- [nm:/25]
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0920] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: scan-periodic-allowed=0, scan-explicit-allowed=1
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0920] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: kickoff: don't scan (periodic scan currently not allowed)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0921] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): activation-stage: synchronously invoke activate_stage2_device_config
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0921] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0921] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (2): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0921] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (1): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0922] global-tracker: sync routing-rule
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0922] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): bringing up device 4
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0922] platform-linux: link: change 4: flags: set 0x1/0x1 ([up] / [up])
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0922] platform-linux: do-request-link: 4
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0922] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 86: 4: wlo1 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? not-init addrgenmode none addr 64:6E:E0:6A:EC:30 permaddr 64:6E:E0:6A:EC:30 brd FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF tx-queue-len 1000 gso-max-size 65536 gso-max-segs 65535 gro-max-size 65536 rx:0,0 tx:0,0
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0922] platform-linux: do-change-link[4]: success
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0922] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: commit update (auto)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0923] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: emit signal (pre-commit)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0923] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: committing IPv4 configuration (update)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0923] netns[db6e9ab158d1a71a]: ecmp-route: committing IPv4 ECMP routes
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0923] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: committing IPv6 configuration (update)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0923] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: emit signal (post-commit)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0923] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'wlo1' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0923] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): powersave is set to 3
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0929] Config: added 'ssid' value 'test'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0929] Config: added 'mode' value '2'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0929] Config: added 'frequency' value '2457'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0929] Config: added 'freq_list' value '2457'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.0929] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0929] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: set bridge (null)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0930] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: assoc[d866563b509e372a]: starting association...
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0931] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip4: check-state: state pending => pending, is_failed=0, is_pending=0, is_started=0 temp_na=0, may-fail-4=1, may-fail-6=1;;;
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0931] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip: check-state: (combined) state none => pending
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0931] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip: set (combined) state pending (was none, reason: check-ip-state)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0931] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip6: check-state: state pending => pending, is_failed=0, is_pending=0, is_started=0 temp_na=0, may-fail-4=1, may-fail-6=1;;;
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0931] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip: check-state: (combined) state pending => pending
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0943] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: set bridge (null) result: successSep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0943] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: assoc[d866563b509e372a]: interface ap_scan set to 2
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0944] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: assoc[d866563b509e372a]: interface PMK lifetime set to 604800
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0944] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: assoc[d866563b509e372a]: interface AP isolation set to 0
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.0949] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: assoc[d866563b509e372a]: network added (/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/Networks/0) (0 blobs left)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345780.0951] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: assoc[d866563b509e372a]: association request successful
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.1003] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: state: disconnected (was inactive, plain property)
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345780.1003] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: state: set state "disconnected" (was "inactive")
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.1004] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Sep 14 21:29:40 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345780.1004] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Sep 14 21:29:42 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345782.5364] ndisc-lndp[0x62fd7bb1bd20,"enp5s0"]: processing libndp events
Sep 14 21:29:47 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345787.8194] ndisc-lndp[0x62fd7bb1bd20,"enp5s0"]: processing libndp events
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <warn>  [1726345805.0632] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) Hotspot network creation took too long, failing activation
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345805.0632] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0633] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (2): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0634] active-connection[c231a285100c5034]: set state deactivated (was activating)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0634] active-connection[c231a285100c5034]: check-master-ready: not signalling (state deactivated, no master)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0634] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (1): 'activation-7'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0635] policy: autoconnect: connection[0x62fd7ba7e810] (wlo1): failed to autoconnect; 2 tries left
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0635] manager: block-autoconnect: device[1f01681469fcb5ac,wlo1]-profile[e420d7b3a4f26031,wlo1]: retries set 2
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0635] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip4: set state none (was pending, reason: ip-state-clear)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0635] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip6: set state none (was pending, reason: ip-state-clear)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <warn>  [1726345805.0635] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'wlo1'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0635] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (2): 'queued-state-change-disconnected'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0635] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): queue-state[disconnected, reason:none, id:2867]: queue state change
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0635] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (1): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0636] dbus-object[c231a285100c5034]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5"
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0637] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): queue-state[disconnected, reason:none, id:2867]: change state
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <info>  [1726345805.0637] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0637] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (2): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0637] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip6: addrgenmode6: set none (already set)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0637] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip6: addrgenmode6: toggle disable_ipv6 sysctl after disabling addr-gen-mode
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0637] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlo1/disable_ipv6': '0'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0637] platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlo1/disable_ipv6' to '1' (current value is '0')
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0637] platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlo1/disable_ipv6' to '0' (current value is '1')
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0638] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0638] manager: default-route-metric: ifindex 4 released
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0638] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): ip: set (combined) state none (was pending, reason: ip-state-clear)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0638] platform-linux: sysctl: setting '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlo1/use_tempaddr' to '0' (current value is identical)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0638] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-ap: removed 64:6E:E0:6A:EC:30 "test"                              [ #  10   0% __ __ W:0000 R:0000 ]          sup:- [nm:/25]
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0639] dbus-object[b36df5791ab8fc7f]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/25"
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0639] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (3): 'autoactivate'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0640] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: scan-periodic-allowed=1, scan-explicit-allowed=1
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0641] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: start periodic scan (0 SSIDs to probe scan)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0641] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: kickoff: periodic scan starting (next scan is scheduled in 3.000 sec)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0641] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: request-scan: request scanning (0 ssids)...
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0641] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: scanning-state: scanning
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0641] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (4): 'wifi-scan'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0641] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: kickoff: don't scan (has scan_request_cancellable)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0641] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: commit reapply
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0641] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: emit signal (pre-commit)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0642] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: committing IPv4 configuration (reapply)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0642] netns[db6e9ab158d1a71a]: ecmp-route: committing IPv4 ECMP routes
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0642] global-tracker: sync ip4-route
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0642] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: committing IPv6 configuration (reapply)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0642] global-tracker: sync ip6-route
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0642] global-tracker: sync mptcp-addr (reapply)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0642] platform-linux: mptcp: 2 addresses dumped
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0643] platform-linux: mptcp: address[0000]: 10.151.0.2 id 1 flags subflow ifindex 3
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0643] platform-linux: mptcp: address[0001]: 2001:8b0:1418:0:7f58:d53f:35ab:5d58 id 2 flags subflow ifindex 3
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0643] l3cfg[f6069bb041b66387,ifindex=4]: emit signal (post-commit)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0643] global-tracker: sync routing-rule
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] config: device-state: write #4 (/run/NetworkManager/devices/4); managed=managed, route-metric-default=0-0
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0645] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): queueing DNS updates (1)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] policy: set-hostname: updating hostname (routing and dns)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] hostname: transient hostname retrieval failed
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] policy: get-hostname: "dragon"
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] hostname: transient hostname retrieval failed
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] policy: get-hostname: "dragon"
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] policy: set-hostname: hostname already set to 'dragon' (from system configuration)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0645] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): DNS configuration did not change
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0645] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv4] periodic-check: re-scheduled in 1000 milliseconds (1 seconds interval)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0645] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv4] start check (seq:239, periodic-check)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] connectivity: (wlo1,IPv4,239) skip connectivity check due to no carrier
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0646] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv6] periodic-check: re-scheduled in 1000 milliseconds (1 seconds interval)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0646] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv6] start check (seq:240, periodic-check)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] connectivity: (wlo1,IPv6,240) skip connectivity check due to no carrier
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (3): 'in-state-change'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] active-connection[c231a285100c5034]: disposing
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (2): 'queued-state-change-disconnected'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (1): 'autoactivate'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] connectivity: (wlo1,IPv4,239) check completed: NONE; no carrier
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0646] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv4] complete check (seq:239, state:NONE)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0646] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv4] periodic-check: re-scheduled in 1999 milliseconds (2 seconds interval)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0646] connectivity: (wlo1,IPv6,240) check completed: NONE; no carrier
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0647] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv6] complete check (seq:240, state:NONE)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0647] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): connectivity: [IPv6] periodic-check: re-scheduled in 1999 milliseconds (2 seconds interval)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0658] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: call-remove-network: success
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0660] secret-agent[00bcde068867898f]: name-owner-changed: disconnected
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.0660] agent-manager: agent[00bcde068867898f,:1.153/nmcli-connect/0]: agent unregistered or disappeared
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0660] secret-agent[00bcde068867898f]: finalized
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0666] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: request-scan: request scanning success
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0666] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: scan request completed (D-Bus request)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0711] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: scanning: yes (plain property)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.0712] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: scanning: yes
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.5678] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: scan request completed (after extra delay)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.5812] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: ignore
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.5873] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: scanning: no (plain property)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.5873] sup-iface[f00f9e4deba2c2d4,0,wlo1]: scanning: no
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.5874] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: scanning-state: idle (notify last-scan)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.5875] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: kickoff: don't scan (rate limited for another 0.200 sec after previous scan)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.5876] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): add_pending_action (2): 'autoactivate'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.5876] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (1): 'wifi-scan'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.5877] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): remove_pending_action (0): 'autoactivate'
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <debug> [1726345805.7881] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: start periodic scan (0 SSIDs to probe scan)
Sep 14 21:30:05 dragon NetworkManager[1645]: <trace> [1726345805.7882] device[1f01681469fcb5ac] (wlo1): wifi-scan: kickoff: periodic scan starting (next scan is scheduled in 3.000 sec

It looks like the problem is related to wpa_supplicant and access point scanning. I cannot find a way to turn that off via netplan.
Anyone got any ideas?
